# dotPeek decompile dll

Tags: c#, dll, decompiling, dotpeek

So we had one old dll at our server, which was made by us, and source code was lost long ago, i tryed to debug .dll file (was made by one of our programmers) and the decompiled code was a bit protected so in some classes variables are like this:

```
private static List<string> \u0023\u003DqiItWZoAhR0uPggAduB3lPA\u003D\u003D = new List<string>();
```

So is there any way we can recover this variable names so at least we get some info on how thing is working ?

Comment: When you say protected, do you mean it's been obfuscated by something like .Net obfuscate, for example.. If so, then the variable names will be either hashed or encrypted. I don't think there is a way around this since it is used to protect against decompiling.

Comment: Yes it was probably used we can get with which was protected but i believe this wotn help us ?

Comment: If the obfuscated identifiers follow legal rules for identifiers when present in source code you should be able to use refactoring tools inside Visual Studio to rename those when you discover their meaning. But if it was easy to reverse an obfuscated assembly, the obfuscator tool wouldn't be doing its job now would it?

Comment: Also, stop obfuscating your own assemblies that you host on your own servers. That seems like just adding unnecessary steps to make things unnecessary difficult. Stack traces from exceptions when things go wrong is also going to be completely impossible to decode.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like some obfuscator work. 
I'm affraid you can only manual change this :(